# In Drupal 8, using the Deploy Module, I am not able to deploy the embedded or attached images/files, has anyone been able to get it to work with that?

Tags: drupal, synchronization, drupal-8, drupal-modules, embedded-media

Drupal 8, Deploy module is deploying content and data between two instances/installs, however, while passing the src modification that points to the embedded and attached media file (images in this case) it doesn't find the file as the file does not get transferred/copied.

I have tried a lot of the solutions already presented online with the UUID as well as giving administrator permissions to the replicator user

I can't find any errors (even with verbose enabled) and at the same point as pointed out here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/266197/deploy-media-field-images-from-staging-to-production?newreg=acce42bf07294dee9d66fe29b7315fa6

I am wondering if anyone else managed to get the module to transfer files or was able to create a workaround in which a file sync action between the two folders (on different servers) is being triggered when the drupal cron job is running.